# navigation disconnect fragments and view

Tags: android

I have navigation competent just go from Fragment A to B , however going back from B to A , making A loose everything, text field data, click linstners, there is code inside oncreeteView to init view also does be called , ViewModel live data no more active

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/booking_nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appBarLayout"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
```

Oncreate

```
val navHostFragment =
  supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.booking_nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
val navController = navHostFragment.navController
val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
  topLevelDestinationIds = setOf( R.id.bookingFragment),
  fallbackOnNavigateUpListener = ::onSupportNavigateUp
)

toolbar_details.setupWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)

setSupportActionBar(toolbar_details)
supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)
supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
```

In nav_graph

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/a">


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/a"
        android:name=".A"
        android:label=" ">
     <action
                android:id="@+id/action_a_to_b"
                app:destination="@id/b" />
```

Fragment A :

```
private val viewModelFilter: filterViewModel by sharedViewModel()
```

Answer (score -1):

do you have an Activity to hold the fragments or it's just two fragments A and B?

I think the easy way to use one based Main Activity having the fragments on it
and init the main view Model in the Activity and shear it at the fragments so you keep the data alive because its lifecycle ended with the fragment associated with it

And since the viewModel expires and onCleared runs at the end of the life of the fragment from which the information is reduced, so it must be created in the Activity so that it remains running and the fragment is reduced from it.

here is an example code :
1- in main Activity

```
viewModel=ViewModelProvider(this).get(ViewModel::class.java)
```

2- in the first fragment you to get the same viewModel instance from the main actitivty

```
activity.let {
viewModel=ViewModelProvider(it!!).get(ViewModel::class.java)
```

}

and this way you get the view Model alive throw the fragment's lifecycle and destroyed when the activity is finished